# spin.js / angular-spinner: how to position spin into DOM element (plunker demo included)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, spin.js

I've found [angular-spinner](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner) which is based on [spin.js](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/), and I want to use it. Anyway, the example found in angular-spinner's README (http://plnkr.co/edit/BGLUYcylbIVJRz6ztbhf?p=preview) doesn't work as I expect. I want the spinner to overlay the selected DOM element and not the global window.

I have modified the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/9xsi8OFui3VeYuZ810VZ?p=preview - here you can see that there is a `<div>` element with red background. The spinner is outside it - what can I do to make it centered inside the red-background div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
position: relative;
```

in that red container

http://plnkr.co/edit/oPStHrLHXKUq3HE9pET0?p=preview

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz It is how the plugin was made. From what I seen, it used to force the spin to be centered within its container (for vertical and horizontal centering).

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz Also I think the plugin was designed to use with a specific responsive framework (or it was tested with one). Since most of responsive framework will automatically add `position: relative;` to pretty much every elements...  Just my opinion...